# List indices must be integers and not dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

My json file look likes this and I'm trying to access the data from it.

```
{
"stats": [
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "WarL0cK",
        "position": "toplane",
        "playerSlug": "warl0ck",
        "team": "BKT",
        "gamesPlayed": 6,
        "kda": 1.5,
        "kills": 12,
        "deaths": 20,
        "assists": 18,
        "killParticipation": 0.6666666666666666,
        "csPerMin": 5.917136743824159,
        "cs": 1014,
        "minutesPlayed": 171,
        "teamSlug": "bangkok-titans"
    },
```

And my script is mentioned below. When i run it it gives the error:list indices must be integers, not dict

```
import csv
import json

json_file='PlayerStats.json'
with open(json_file, 'r') as json_data:
x = json.load(json_data)

f = csv.writer(open("playerstats.csv", "w"))

f.writerow(["stats", "id", "name", "position","playerSlug", "team",     "gamesPlayed", "kda", "kills", "deaths", "assists", "killParticipation", "csPerMin", "cs", "minutesPlayed", "teamSlug"])

stats=x["stats"]
for key in x["stats"]:
    f.writerow([ 
            x["stats"][key]["id"], 
            x["stats"][key]["name"],
            x["stats"][key]["position"],
            x["stats"][key]["playerSlug"],
            x["stats"][key]["team"],
            x["stats"][key]["gamesPlayed"],
            x["stats"][key]["kda"],
            x["stats"][key]["kills"],
            x["stats"][key]["deaths"],
            x["stats"][key]["assists"],
            x["stats"][key]["killParticipation"],
            x["stats"][key]["csPerMin"],
            x["stats"][key]["cs"],
            x["stats"][key]["minutesPlayed"],
            x["stats"][key]["teamSlug"]])
```

I think there is some problem in parsing the list from dictionaries. Please help.

Comment: But still its not working

Comment: Could you edit your question to tell us which line gives the error, and add a tag for the computer language you are using?

Comment: (x["stats"][key]["id"]): this line is getting the error. And the language I am using is python

Comment: If you had read the post I suggested this one is a duplicate of, you would have tried with `key["id"]` instead of `x["stats"][key]["id"]`.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. You were really a help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here stat contains a list of Json objects/dicts, therefore when you iterate over stat each "key" is a dict not an index. Simply use:

```
key["id"]
```

Answer (score 0):

x["stats"] is a list. Not a dict.

So please change `x["stats"][key]["id"]` to `x["stats"][0][key]["id"]`

```
for key in x["stats"]:
    f.writerow([ 
            x["stats"][0][key]["id"],
            ....
```